# How to disable custom styling that also applies to the Gutenberg Component Panel

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

With the hook 'enqueue_block_editor_assets' you can enqueue styles and scripts for the Gutenberg Block editor. However, when you have your own styling for example h1, h2 tags, it also applies to the component panel.

How can you separate the two? So that the styling only applies to the blocks and not the component panel. See screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

The thing is. I use SCSS that compiles to one stylesheet. It makes no sense creating another stylesheet only for the block editor when you already have all those styling. A prefix would help but maybe there is another solution?